# How to use VLOOKUP function with IFNA function

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am using VLOOKUP to merge data from one spreadsheet with data in another, I want the VLOOKUP function to return Does not exist where the data does not match my query.

IFNA((VLOOKUP(A6,'Employee Rates'!$A$2:$B$6,2,FALSE)),'Does Not Exist')

Comment: wrap it in double quotes as such `"Does Not Exist"`

Comment: =IFNA((VLOOKUP(A6,'Employee Rates'!$A$2:$B$6,2,FALSE)),"Does not exist")